# Cayley Hamilton use to find higher power of non diagnalizable matrix. Reduction not easy for the characteristic equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, cayley-hamilton

Mat $A= \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\
        1&0&1\\
        0&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Find $A^{30}$.

Cannot diagonalize. Not generic reduction of characteristic equation with eigenvalue $1,1, -1$.

Comment: Please don't leave the problem statement out of the body of the Question, where you have room to give a full statement of the problem you want help with.  If you know the characteristic equation is needed for this problem, start by finding the characteristic *polynomial* of $A$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Amar: you must have made a mistake, this matrix is diagnolizable.  The eigenvalues should be $$\lambda_{1,2,3} = 0, 1, 1$$

Comment: If you did have a matrix which wasn't diagonalizable, you could probably still use Jordan normal form, along with the fact: for example, if $A = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ and $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(A) = \begin{bmatrix} p(\lambda) & p'(\lambda) & p''(\lambda)/2 & p'''(\lambda)/6 \\ 0 & p(\lambda) & p'(\lambda) & p''(\lambda)/2 \\ 0 & 0 & p(\lambda) & p'(\lambda) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & p(\lambda) \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Sorry this is not the matrix I solved for. I am making edit.

Answer (score 4):

$A^2=A$. What else do you need?

Comment: I have made the edit to the matrix now. Pardon for the mistake.

Comment: @Amar Seeing that you just now realized that you didn't ask the right question (2 hours after the fact), you might as well leave this question as it was and ask a new question...